# Is there a way to install programs through bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm fairly new to bash's sudo commands etc. I recently wanted to upgrade my psql and when i tried to brew install it, it was not happening. Turns out that brew itself had stopped supporting my old version of mac os in 2021. Meaning I couldn't do anything with brew. Only first time when i ran brew update it gave me the following:

```
$brew update
warning: unable to unlink .gitignore: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink .yardopts: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink CODEOFCONDUCT.md: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink CONTRIBUTING.md: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink LICENSE.txt: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink SUPPORTERS.md: Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'README.md' (Permission denied)
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

'brew update' , 'brew install' or 'brew doctor' - nothing worked. after that when ever i try, i get `No such file or directory`:

```
$brew install postgresql@12
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: No such file or directory
```

Wanted to know if bash has commands that can be used to upgrade my psql version? if yes, how?

Answer (score -2):

To me it seems more like a permission problem, have you tried prepending `sudo` to `brew update`?

Comment: sudo brew update gave me : `sudo: brew: command not found `

Comment: Which OS version are you running?

Comment: it's mac os 10.10.5

Comment: [You should not use sudo with brew](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad).